# Как соединиться с бд MySQL которая расположена на локальной машине?

Tags: mysql, node.js, access

У меня есть проект *nodejs*, такие настройки подключения к *MySQL*:

```
db:{
        host:"localhost",
        user:"test",
        password:"1111",
        database:"test-db"
    }
```

У юзера стоит *%* в хосте.

Сам *MySQL*, вместе с *nginx* и прочим, лежит в виртуалке с *убунтой*, т.е. доступ по обычному внутреннему *ip*.

Это нужно для того, чтобы с винды коннектиться по локальному виртуаловскому *ip* к базе данных на *убунте*, иначе содержать две копии *MySQL* и на виртуалке и на *винде* - неудобно.

Когда я в качестве хоста указываю `192.168.56.101:3306` - выдает ошибку подключения.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вам надо указать в конфигурации *mysqld* (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`), чтобы он слушал не только локальный адрес (обычно `127.0.0.1`), но и внешние.

для этого надо либо закомментировать строку(-и), содержащую директиву `bind-addrss`, либо написать в ней «слушать всё»:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

---

> по обычному внутреннему ip

для машины это **внешний** адрес. внутренние адреса — это те, что закреплены за внутренним сетевым *loopback*-интерфейсом (обычно закрепляется целая сеть, состоящая из 16777214 *ip-адресов* — `127/8`).

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А с чем связаны такие долгие задержки при запросах к бд? Даже когда с такой настрокой внутри виртуалки приложение работает  host:"192.168.56.101". Когда было localhost указано, бд быстро работала.

Comment: попробуйте задать этот вопрос техподдержке вашей системы виртуализации.

Comment: это все в домашних условиях. У меня на винде есть апач с phpmyadmin, я в конфиге прописал $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '192.168.56.101'; и при этом оч долго грузятся страницы (все запросы к бд), при этом nodejs работает хорошо сейчас. В чем может быть причина? Есть догадки какие-либо?

Comment: нашел ответ, добавил в конфиг мускула skip-name-resolve